# .htaccess rewrite help request

Tags: .htaccess

I am hoping to gain some help with a small trouble I am experiencing with configuring a .htaccess file. Basically, I want to retrieve 2 variables from a URL String.

For example:

If someone entered www.website.com.au/folder/category/item.php

I would like the .htaccess to retrieve the last two variables (being Category and Item) and parse them to my display-item.php page.

I have a rough idea of what I need to be doing (As per below) though with all the tutes I have been reading I am a little confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

:) Paul

```
RewriteRule /folder/(.*)/(.*).php /folder/display-item.php?category=$1&item=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/(.*).php /folder/display-item.php?category=$1&item=$2 [L]
```

Works a treat. Managed to get it working.